# How can I send an array of javascript object to a php script via $.post?

Tags: php, jquery, json, object, .post

I have a table of data on my page. The columns are "start", "end", "comment", and "options". Within the options column is a button to delete the row, and a button that makes a row of the table editable. This allows the values of "start", "end", and "comment" to be changed. Clicking it again finishes the editing process. Finally, there is a way to add another row to the table. All of this works as expected.

I want to add a button at the bottom that creates an array out of the data in the table, that looks like this (represented as JSON purely for ease of showing to SO: not required):

```
[
    {
        "start"     :"2009/08/01",
        "end"       :"2009/08/08",
        "comment"   :"an example date.",
    },
    {
        "start"     :"2009/07/01",
        "end"       :"2009/07/08",
        "comment"   :"another example date, a month earlier.",
    },
    {
        "start"     :"2000/07/01",
        "end"       :"2000/07/08",
        "comment"   :"another example date, a year earlier. You get the idea.",
    }
]
```

I shouldn't have too much trouble building the array, but once I have, how can I post it to a backend php script (which will then use `put_csv()` to write the data to a file)? Ideally, it would be availiable server-side in a array format, to allow validation.

I'm happy to use jquery, if it's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you end it to the server depends on what do you want to archieve. If you want to load a new page, which will process the data, you can use an usual form with hidden inputs. Alternatively, if you want to process is in the background via AJAX, use `jQuery.ajax` as CRasco said. Either way you use, you need to convert the structured array into a simple key/value list.

One option is to generate a JSON document (I don't think jQuery provides a function for this, but you can easily find something) and use a single field with the serialized document. Then on the server side you would use `json_decode` to get the array back. If you are using the AJAX method, the data option in `jQuery.ajax` call would contain:

```
{
    'data': '[{"start":"2009/08/01","end":"2009/08/08","comment":"an example date."},...'
}
```

A better approach would be to serialize it into a list of fields in a format that PHP natively understands. That means you have to do nothing special, and `$_POST['data']` will contain the array. For example:

```
{
    'data[0][start]': '2009/08/01',
    'data[0][end]': '2009/08/08',
    'data[0][comment]': 'an example date.',
    'data[1][start]': '2009/07/01',
    'data[1][end]': '2009/07/08',
    'data[1][comment]': 'another example date, a month earlier.',
    ... 
}
```

If you are using the form method, you need to generate input fields like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[0][start]" value="2009/08/01" />
```

Comment: I didn't know that associative (or multidimensional) arrays could be passed by php. How could I go about contructing said array in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use jQuery. Here is the page for the $.post() function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

One caveat is that $.post() is a wrapper for the $.ajax() function that is simplified and eliminates your ability to set callbacks for anything but a successful post. For important transactions via AJAX, I would use this:

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax

An example being:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')}),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   });
```